# USB mass storage devices are read-only when connected via a Thunderbolt dock

Tags: usb, lenovo, thunderbolt

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Yoga c930. I have a [Lenovo Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 dock](https://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/solutions/acc100356-thinkpad-thunderbolt-3-dock-overview-and-service-parts). The dock is connected to the laptop via a Thunderbolt cable. I have a DisplayPort monitor connected to it that works fine, and I can get power through it.

What doesn't work consistently at all is USB. There are at least two, probably related issues:

1. Sometimes, USB devices connected to the dock just aren't seen by the laptop. I can get around this by rebooting the laptop.
2. However, USB mass storage devices, if the laptop can see them, are in *read only*. For example, with a pendrive:

```
jack@c930:/media/jack/Lexar$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Read-only file system
```

I've also had issues such as not being able to even copy files from the device, or play videos directly from it with VLC, so I think the problem is even worse than just being read-only.

I have a wireless USB mouse and keyboard connected to the same hub right now, which seem to work fine. They're subject to issue (1) as well, but for instance, at this moment the mouse and keyboard are working through the dock, but issue (2) persists.

Right now I'd like to focus on issue #2. Assuming I can get my laptop to see the device, how can I get the thing into read-write mode?

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  -f` as you connect the cable.Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: The problem turned out to be the USB stick was badly formatted. Because I'd previously had similar problems with a *different* USB mass storage device with this Thunderbolt dock (which I know is formatted just fine), one issue obscured another. There are still strange issues with this dock, but this specific problem was solved by just formatting the USB stick, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.