# Why is my USB stick owned by user 99?

Tags: usb, permissions, users, usb-drive, thunderbolt

This is a follow-on/spin-off of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338484/usb-mass-storage-devices-are-read-only-when-connected-via-a-thunderbolt-dock?noredirect=1#comment2285498_1338484).

Whenever I connect a USB mass storage device to my Thunderbolt laptop dock, it's in some kind of read-only mode. The output of `ll` for my USB flash drive is:

```
drwxrwxr-x  1   99   99   11 nov.  19 17:43 Lexar/
```

So it's owned by user 99, in group 99, and I don't have read access. As far as I can tell (looking at `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`), there is no such user or group.

What is this mysterious user 99? Can I obtain ownership of the device?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this came from the the drive being badly formatted. I reformatted the thing in the Disks program and the problem went away.